# Python Curses iniscr() without Clearing Screen?

Tags: python, curses

For Python 2.7, is there a way to initialize curses without have the screen blank/clear? Right now I am using

```
stdscr = curses.initscr()
```

Answer (score 1):

No. The python curses library is built on the curses/ncurses library.  `initscr` always clears the screen so the library starts with the screen in a known state (empty).

Comment: can you suggest a alternate library that does not clear the screen?